# how to assign object value to variable without reference

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use Node.js and I want to assign current value of A to variable B.Value of B should not change when changes happen to A.

```
var A = new Date();
var B = A;
DP.setMonth(A.getMonth() - 1);
console.log(B); //get A result
```

Comment: You can't directly, objects are always assigned by reference, not value. You would have to clone the object.

Comment: replace `var B = A;` with `var B = new Date(A);` or simply `var B = new Date();`

Comment: this is only a example if I assign object value to another variable, that variable values always change with first object.how to create another object with the assigning object value.

Answer (score 2):

> I use Node.js and I want to assign current value of A to variable
>   B.Value of B should not change when changes happen to A.

Simply replace

```
var B = A;
```

with

```
var B = new Date(A);
```

If you want to use value of A, but still want both of them to be isolated from each other than you need to make a new object rather than simply referring to old one.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new `Date` object and seed it with A's value.

```
var A = new Date();
var B = new Date(A.getTime());

A.setMonth(A.getMonth() - 1);

console.log(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this(clone objects in JS) is to use a third party utility library called [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs).

Using lodash you can simply clone or deep clone(for nested objects) by using the following functions:
[_.clone()](https://lodash.com/docs#clone) or [_cloneDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep)

Install Lodash by **npm install --save lodash**

```
var _ = require(lodash)
var A = new Date();
var B = _.cloneDeep(A);
DP.setMonth(A.getMonth() - 1);
console.log(B);// B will not change
```

You can use these methods to clone most of JS objects. **Lodash is highly optimized for performance** so it would be better to use Lodash than manually cloning each keys. Lodash also offers other extremely usefull functions.

Comment: loadsh is very heavy, finally adding a lot of package every one with lodash produce a big file, now i'm working hard to avoid lodash